# Sorted Linked List: optimized add/remove/reordering of elements

Tags: c++, optimization, linked-list, a-star

I'm doing an implementation of the A* pathfinding algorithm based on the pseudocode from Wikipedia, and I'm trying to optimize the performance. I've noted that most of the time is wasted on handling nodes in the "open" set of nodes (basically nodes to examine), so I've been doing my best to make it faster.

(Background, feel free to skip to the code)
Basically, I have a set of nodes and what I do with it is the following:

- Find the node with the lowest score
- Check if a node is contained within the set
- Remove a node from the set
- Add a node to the set

By using a sorted linked list, finding the lowest score goes from checking all elements to fetching the first. Adding nodes becomes more complicated, but usually doesn't require traversing the entire list, so it saves time. Removing is the same regardless. For checking if a node is in the set, I use an array map with direct access so it can be done quickly at the cost of some additional memory.

```
class OpenNodeSet
{
public:
    OpenNodeSet(void);
    ~OpenNodeSet(void);

    void add(GraphNode *n);
    void remove(GraphNode *n);
    void reinsert(GraphNode *n);
    bool contains(GraphNode *n);
    GraphNode* top(void);

    int size(void)          {   return elements;    }
    bool empty(void)        {   return (elements == 0); }

private:
    typedef struct listNode {
        GraphNode *node;
        struct listNode *next;
    } listNode_t;

    listNode_t *root;
    int elements;
    unsigned __int8 map[1024][1024];
};

OpenNodeSet::OpenNodeSet(void)
{
    root = NULL;
    elements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
            map[i][j] = 0;
}

OpenNodeSet::~OpenNodeSet(void)
{
    while (root != NULL) {
        listNode_t *tmp = root->next;
        free(root);
        root = tmp;
    }
}

void OpenNodeSet::add(GraphNode *n)
{
    listNode_t **head;
    for (head = &root; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next)
        if ((*head)->node->f_score > n->f_score)
            break;

    listNode_t *newNode = (listNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(listNode_t));
    newNode->node = n;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
    map[n->x][n->y] = 1;
    elements++;
}

void OpenNodeSet::remove(GraphNode *n)
{
    listNode_t **head;
    for (head = &root; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next)
        if ((*head)->node == n) {
            listNode_t *tmp = *head;
            *head = (*head)->next;
            free(tmp);
            map[n->x][n->y] = 0;
            elements--;
            return;
        }
}

void OpenNodeSet::reinsert(GraphNode *n)
{
    listNode_t **head, **bookmark = NULL;
    listNode_t *ln = NULL;
    int pos = 0;
    for (head = &root; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next, pos++) {
        if (bookmark == NULL && (*head)->node->f_score > n->f_score)
            bookmark = head;
        if (ln == NULL && (*head)->node == n) {
            ln = *head;
            *head = (*head)->next;
        }
        if (bookmark && ln)
            break;
    }

    ln->next = (*bookmark)->next;
    *bookmark = ln;
}

bool OpenNodeSet::contains(GraphNode *n)
{
    return map[n->x][n->y]==1;
}

GraphNode* OpenNodeSet::top(void)
{
    return root->node;
}
```

The code is not as clean/efficient as it should be in some places, right now I'm just in get-it-to-work-mode. Problem is, it doesn't work.

The reinsert function is there because often I will need to change the score of a node, and thus also its position in the list. Instead of having one list traversal for removing it and another for inserting it, I use a single traversal to find both the position to reinsert the node, and the node itself which should save me allocating memory and another traversal. Problem is, sometimes the reinsert function fails to find a node to reinsert, which is to say, the node doesn't exist (and it doesn't, I've manually checked it). This shouldn't happen though. If I ignore it, eventually I get a segmentation fault (or the equivalent in Visual Studio), but I'm not sure if that's just the result of ignoring it. Here's the function for finding a path:

```
void Graph::findPath(int start_x, int start_y, int goal_x, int goal_y)
{
    GraphNode *start = map[start_x][start_y];
    GraphNode *goal = map[goal_x][goal_y];
    OpenNodeSet open;
    NodeSet closed;

    open.add(start);
    start->g_score = 0;
    start->f_score = distance(start, goal);

    while (!open.empty()) {
        //FIND MIN F_SCORE NODE AND REMOVE NODE FROM OPEN LIST
        GraphNode *curr = open.top();
        open.remove(curr);

        //REACHED GOAL?
        if (curr == goal) {
            reconstructPath(curr);
            break;
        }

        //ADD MIN COST NODE TO CLOSED LIST
        closed.add(curr);

        //FOR EACH NEIGHBOR OF NODE
        for (int i = 0; i < curr->neighbor_count; i++) {
            GraphNode *neighbor = curr->neighbors[i].node;
            float cost = curr->neighbors[i].cost;

            float tmp_g = curr->g_score + cost;
            if (closed.contains(neighbor) && tmp_g >= neighbor->g_score)
                continue;

            bool inOpenSet = open.contains(neighbor);
            if (!inOpenSet || tmp_g < neighbor->g_score) {
                neighbor->parent = curr;
                neighbor->g_score = tmp_g;
                neighbor->f_score = tmp_g + distance(neighbor, goal);

                if (inOpenSet)
                    open.reinsert(neighbor);
                else
                    open.add(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something is clearly going on with my list implementation, but I can't figure out what. When I try to test it with other values, it behaves like it should. I have no idea if `reinsert()` works like it should since it gets input it shouldn't. Interestingly, if I use the following instead of the `reinsert()/add()` calls:

```
        if (inOpenSet) {
            open.remove(neighbor);
        }
        open.add(neighbor);
```

...things seem to be fine. I even checked if remove at some point found an element that wasn't there, and apparently, it wasn't. This makes me suspect the `reinsert()` function, but I'm not as certain as I'd like to be. For all I know, using remove/add instead could just make the program work, but give an incorrect result. Either way, I've been staring myself blind and need another perspective.

Can someone see what is going on here? It seems to be some sort of special case since the problem is rare, but I can't reproduce it. When I've tested it with artificial values, `reinsert()` does what I expect it to without complaints.

PS. Any other optimization tips or a better heuristic cost estimate than distance between the nodes is welcome as well. Mostly, this specific part is all about speed and less about memory usage, but both are good. Oh, and Stack Overflow virginity gone.

**EDIT:**

Turns out a nice dinner and a few hours of spare time was all I needed. Last two lines of reinsert() should've read:

```
ln->next = *bookmark;
*bookmark = ln;
```

Not sure if I did it right when I tested it and didn't notice the code didn't match, but there you go. Reduced the time spent on fixing a re-scored node in my particular test case by 25% compared to the regular remove+add operation.

Still, more ideas on how to make it better is always welcome. I'd like to be able to do a binary search to find the insertion position, but I can't think of a good way to do it while not having to shovel around ton of memory around in huge fixed-size arrays or constant realloc() calls.

Comment: (1) Why are you using a linked list? It's a waste of time. (2) Why are using a *sorted* linked list? It's a waste of time. (3) Why are you using *your own implementation* of the linked list? It's a waste of time.

Comment: What would you suggest I use? I've tested searching through the set instead of sorting it, and it's slower than using a sorted set. I've tried the STL Vector and List classes with iterators instead of my own, and both are slower than my implementation. The test case I ran just before posting this clocked the std::vector implementation at 31 sec to complete, while mine took 0.26 seconds, while both produce the same result. The other test case I tried took 0.8 seconds for mine, and I don't know how long the vector took because I got bored and shut it down.

Comment: You need a data structure that has fast element addition and fast minimal element removal. That would be the *priority queue*. The Wikipedia article on A* mentions it, unsurprizingly. I'm not sure how you have managed to use the standard library with such devastating results. Perhaps you were using a Microsoft compiler and ran a debug build. That could explain 100-fold decrease in performance.

Comment: Ah, damnit, that would explain it. First time I'm using Visual Studio for C++. Usually I only use it for C# and pretty much Linux/GCC exclusively for C/C++ (alas, my Linux VM is dead and I'm sitting on a 3G connection). I'll just add that to the growing list of annoyances. You are right, it was faster. Okay then, vector it is for now, trying priority queue tomorrow. Thanks.